# Having trouble with adding 2 numbers and getting the program to display 2 digit numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to modify this program to be able to print out a two digit number. Input numbers are between 1-9 and output is the sum of the two single digit numbers, so the output should be between 0 and 18. A hint form the teacher was that the input should be in the format of 00-18. I translated it as best I could.

```
cr equ 13 ; Vognretur
lf equ 10 ; Linjeskift
SYS_EXIT equ 1
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

; Datasegment
section .bss
siffer resb 4

; Datasegment
section .data
   meld db "Skriv to ensifrede tall skilt med mellomrom.",cr,lf
      db "Summen av tallene maa vaere mindre enn 10.",cr,lf
meldlen equ $ - meld
feilmeld db cr,lf, "Skriv kun sifre!",cr,lf
feillen equ $ - feilmeld
crlf db cr,lf
crlflen equ $ - crlf

; Codesegment with program
section .text

global _start
_start:
mov edx,meldlen
mov ecx,meld
mov ebx,STDOUT
mov eax,SYS_WRITE
int 80h

; Read number, read number returns in ecx
; Succesfull return if edx=0
call lessiffer
cmp edx,0 ; Test
jne Slutt 
mov eax,ecx ; First digit saved in reg eax

call lessiffer
; Read second digit
; success: edx=0, number in ecx
cmp edx,0 ;Test 
jne Slutt
mov ebx,ecx ; second digit saved in reg ebx

call nylinje
add eax,ebx
mov ecx,eax
call skrivsiffer ; Print out value in ecx as a single digit number

Slutt:
mov eax,SYS_EXIT
mov ebx,0
int 80h

; ---------------------------------------------------------
skrivsiffer:
; Prints digit saved in ecx. No value check
push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx
add ecx,'0' ; converter tall til ascii.
mov [siffer],ecx
mov ecx,siffer
mov edx,1
mov ebx,STDOUT
mov eax,SYS_WRITE
int 80h
pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
ret

; ---------------------------------------------------------
lessiffer:
; searches past blank spaces to next non-blank
; Next non-blank is returned ti ecx
  push eax
  push ebx

Lokke:
  ; Reads sign from keyboard
  mov eax,SYS_READ
  mov ebx,STDIN
  mov ecx,siffer
  mov edx,1
  int 80h
  mov ecx,[siffer]
  cmp ecx,' '
  je Lokke
  cmp ecx,'0' ; checks if digit is between 0-9
  jb Feil
  cmp ecx,'9'
  ja Feil
  sub ecx,'0' ; converts ascii to number.
  mov edx,0 ; signals successfull input
  pop ebx
  pop eax
  ret ; Vellykket retur

Feil:
  mov edx,feillen
  mov ecx,feilmeld
  mov ebx,STDERR
  mov eax,SYS_WRITE
  int 80h
  mov edx,1 ; singaled failed input
  pop ebx
  pop eax
  ret ; failed return

; ---------------------------------------------------------
; Move cursor to the left on next line
nylinje:
  push eax
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push edx
  mov edx,crlflen
  mov ecx,crlf
  mov ebx,STDOUT
  mov eax,SYS_WRITE
  int 80h
  pop edx
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop eax
  ret

; End _start
```

There is a lot of code, I know but sence I'm new to assembly I'm not quite sure where to modify. I would guess that the modification would be in the skrivsiffer function.

Comment: The trivial way given the constraints is just something like `if (x > 9) { putchar('1'); x -= 10; }` then print the single digit remaining.

Comment: that would probably work fine if it was a different language than assembly

Comment: As the to the hint you were given `be in the format 00-18` makes me think you're expected to be working with BCD (Binary Coded Decimals). If that is the case, then your code is wrong and the hint @jester gave you wouldn't work.

Comment: The code that is given, the the the exact code from the assignment

Comment: Which way do you want to do it then, BCD or Binary?

Comment: Obviously I have only given you the logic. I trust you can code the needed steps in assembly.